# Send file handle as argument in perl

Tags: perl, filehandle

Is it possible to send a **file handle** as an argument to a subroutine in PERL?

If yes, can you help with a sample code snippet showing how to receive it and use it in the subroutine?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score 12):

You're using lexical variables (`open(my $fh, ...)`) as you should, right? If so, you don't have to do anything special.

```
sub f { my ($fh) = @_; print $fh "Hello, World!\n"; }
f($fh);
```

If you're using a glob (`open(FH, ...)`), just pass a reference to the glob.

```
f(\*STDOUT);
```

Though many places will also accept the glob itself.

```
f(*STDOUT);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it using .below is the sample code for the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (MYFILE, 'temp');

printit(\*MYFILE);

sub printit {
    my $fh = shift;
    while (<$fh>) {
        print;
    }
}
```

below is the test:

```
> cat temp
1
2
3
4
5
```

the perl script sample

```
> cat temp.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (MYFILE, 'temp');
printit(\*MYFILE);
sub printit {
    my $fh = shift;
    while (<$fh>) {
        print;
    } 
}
```

execution

```
> temp.pl
1
2
3
4
5
>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like this:

```
some_func($fh, "hello");
```

where `some_func` is defined like this:

```
sub some_func {
    my ($fh, $str) = @_;
    print { $fh } "The message is: $str\n";
}
```